# Training deep learning a model using extracted features

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I intend to perform multi-camera object detection with fusion.

I managed to save features from the layer (dimension 768x20x20) for the image size 640 (23rd layer) before the detect layer in yolov5m.

My question is how to feed features to the model instead of images and training. I have never trained from features and couldn't find anything related on the internet.

I am able to make changes in the model such as accepting Multi inputs

Comment: I think this is the same as model fine-tuning what you intend to do isn't that? So for example, if you want to continue training the model after the feature layer 768x20x20 you could simply freeze the weights prior to this layer and add more layers as you wish.